# Filling up already made lists from another list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a list with a couple values and i want to split that list into 3 more lists with a length of 8 into lists that are already named. I wrote the code below to do that and it almost works perfectly, the issue is just that in the output, every list starts with 0 and it skips over the value that is supposed to be in place of 0 (eg: 8 and 16). Why is this hapenning?
This is just a test code i have for this example, my main code involves splitting a list with 3.4 million items into 13 lists of 262,144 but im getting the same issue where the first item in each of the 13 lists is replaced by the very first value in the main list.

Any help is very appreciated, Thanks!

```
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []
LIST = [list1, list2, list3]
num = list(range(25))
print(num)
LastRow = len(num)
Cnt = 0
for listed in LIST:
    for num[Cnt] in num:
        while len(listed) < 8:
            listed.append(num[Cnt])
            if Cnt == LastRow-1:
                break
            Cnt = Cnt + 1

print(list1)
print(list2)
print(list3)
print(LIST)

OUTPUT:
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[0, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[0, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [0, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [0, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you modify your `num` list.
If you print your `num` list at the end you will see that it has as many `0s` as you are trying to split the list in to part.

Below is a working example of a function that splits the list in to a lists of wanted length and number of lists.

```
def separator(list, n, l):
    """"
    Separates the list in to n lists with the lenght l 
    The last list can be shorter than l
    """
    
    list_of_lists = []
    for i in range(n):
        list_of_lists.append(list[i*l:(i+1)*l])
        
    return list_of_lists

separator(list(range(25)), 3, 8)

# [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
# [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
# [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]]
```

If you do not need to have all of the lists in memory I advise to check generators that could generate each `list` as you need it.

```
def separator_gen(list, n, l):
    """"
    Separates the list in to n lists with the lenght l 
    The last list can be shorter than l
    """
    
    for i in range(n):
        yield list[i*l:(i+1)*l]

my_gen = separator_gen(list(range(25)), 3, 8)

next(my_gen)
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
next(my_gen)
# [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
next(my_gen)
#[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]

next(my_gen)
# raises StopIteration error
```

You can name your lists:

```
# already existing lists for which you assigned new values
your_names = [list1, list2, ...]
for name in your names:
    name = next(my_gen)
```

Comment: Is there a way so that the main list is filling up already existing empty lists. In my main code i need it to fill up these specifically named 13 lists so i can reference them later.

Comment: It would make more sense to name new lists after you create them. Adjsuted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather convoluted way to do it. In python you can just iterate over a list.

Here is my simple approach:

```
starting_list = list(range(25))

tmp_list = []
split_lists = []

for elem in starting_list:
    if len(tmp_list) == 8:
        split_lists.append(tmp_list)
        tmp_list = []
    tmp_list.append(elem)
    if elem == starting_list[-1]:
        split_lists.append(tmp_list)


print(split_lists)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], [24]]
```

If you remove the last `if` statement then a `tmp_list` with less than 8 values in it will not be appended to `split_lists`. I'm not sure if this is intended or not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how could i get specifically list1, list2, list3 filled up? i was thinking trying another for loop after your code to make the lists in your output equal to list1, list2, list3 but i couldnt get it to work. also it might be to computer intensive for over 3 million items and 13 lists

Comment: You could make `split_lists` a `dict` instead of a `list`, then do something like `split_lists['list1'].append(...)` and you could also access them later with `split_lists['list1']`. I don't see a particular benefit of specifically having empty lists beforehand that need to have a particular variable name.

Comment: If you insist on a specific number of lists and the initial data can not evenly be split up, you might loose some data. Is this wanted? See the answer by @Jonas Palačionis, where the last value gets lost in the process.